# why Vector doesn't provide the remove() member function while list provides?

Tags: c++

If I want to delete  all the elements with a value from vector,I call remove **algorithm** and then call vector's erase member function to physically delete it.
     But in the case of list , simple call remove member function and it will delete all elements with that value. 
    I am not sure why vector does't provide the remove MF  while list does it.

For Exp: I want to delete value '4' from vector v.

```
vector<int> v;
vector<int> ::iterator Itr;
for (int i=0; i< 6; i++)
   v.push_back(i*2);
v.push_back(4);
v.push_back(8);
v.push_back(4);
v.erase(remove(v.begin(),v.end(),4), v.end());
```

and for list:

```
list.remove(4); // will delete all the element which has value 4
```

Comment: to be fair all that initial code is just to populate the vector the comparison is: `v.erase(std::remove(v.begin(),v.end(),4), v.end());` vs. `l.remove(4);`

Comment: wrong question. the real question is why `std::list` provides a member function instead of using the general algorithm. and the answer is: list can do better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question is not why `std::vector` does not offer the operation, but rather why does `std::list` offer it. The design of the STL is focused on the separation of the containers and the algorithms by means of iterators, and in all cases where an algorithm can be implemented efficiently in terms of iterators, that is the option.

There are, however, cases where there are specific operations that can be implemented much more efficiently with knowledge of the container. That is the case of removing elements from a container. The cost of using the *remove-erase* idiom is linear in the size of the container (which cannot be reduced much), but that hides the fact that in the worst case all but one of those operations are *copies* of the objects (the only element that matches is the first), and those copies can represent quite a big hidden cost.

By implementing the operation as a method in `std::list` the complexity of the operation will still be linear, but the associated cost for each one of the elements removed is *very low*, a couple of pointer copies and releasing of a node in memory. At the same time, the implementation as part of the list can offer stronger guarantees: pointers, references and iterators to elements that are not erased do not become invalidated in the operation.

Another example of an algorithm that is implemented in the specific container is `std::list::sort`, that uses `mergesort` that is less efficient than `std::sort` but does not require random-access iterators.

So basically, algorithms are implemented as free functions with iterators *unless* there is a strong reason to provide a particular implementation in a concrete container.

Comment: Interesting. But I wonder why `list` has `erase` and `remove` for respectively iterator and value, but `set` has `erase` for both iterator (O(1)) and value (O(log n)) arguments. What's the reason for the different interfaces?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: The standard considers two families of containers, sequences (Section §23.2, `vector`, `list`, `deque`, `vector<bool>`) and associative containers (§23.3, `set`, `map`, `multiset`, `multimap`). The interfaces are uniform within each family, but not across families, but I would not know why the authors of the library decided to share the names for the disparate `erase` operations in associative containers.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the rationale is that `std::list` offers a very efficient `remove` method (if implemented as a doubly linked listed it just adjusts the pointers to the element and deallocates its storage), while element removal for `std::vector` is comparably slow.

The `remove+erase` trick is the standard way which works for all container types that offer the required iterator type. Presumably, the designers of the STL wanted to point out this difference. They could have opted to give all containers a `remove` method, which would be `remove+erase` for all containers except those who knew a better way, but they didn't.

This seems to violate the idea of generic code at a first glance, but I don't think it really does. Having a simple, generic `remove` that is easily accessible makes it easy to write generic code that compiles fine with all container types, but at the end generic code that would run extremely slow in 9 out of 10 cases and blazingly fast in the tenth is not *truly* generic, it just looks so.

The same pattern can be found at `std::map::find` vs. the generic `std::find`.

Answer (score 3):

Removing an element from a vector is much slower than doing so for a list: it is (on average) proportional to the size of the vector, whereas the operation on a list is executed in constant time.

The designers of the standard library decided not to include this feature under the principle of "things that look easy should BE (computationally) easy".

I'm not sure whether I agree with this philosophy, but it's considered a design goal for C++.

Comment: Um, removing a list element by _iterator_ is constant time.  But removing it by _value_ (as the questioner is doing) is O(n) time.  Just like it would be for a vector.

Comment: True. However, finding an element is certainly cheaper than copying a bunch of elements if their size is non-trivial.

Comment: @Nemo, when you remove something from the middle of a `vector`, it has to copy all the elements after it to fill the gap - you dont have to do this with the `list`, its just a quick change of pointer values.

Comment: +1: This is exactly the reason why and if you find that methods you want seem to be missing you should consider using a more appropriate container for the operations you intend to perform.

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to implement the function with the remove-erase idiom and make it as efficient as the current options is, which is basically linear on the size of the vector, and as far as it is documented it should not be a problem (i.e. it is computationally not more expensive than removing the first element of the vector)

Comment: @Node: If you need the operation, then whether the operation is implemented in the container or externally in the *remove-erase* idiom it does not matter: it is an expensive operation in the container.

Comment: @David - having to implement it for your container when there are others that already have it should make you consider if you are using the right one though.  If nothing else, its a way of saying _this container is good for doing this kind of thing_

Comment: @Node: ... and yet it offers `erase( iterator )`, that can be used as `v.erase( v.begin() );` that has exactly the worst case cost of `v.erase( value )`... You have to know the cost of the operations in the container when choosing one over the other, but that is not a reason not to offer an operation, unless, of course, you can already achieve the same effect with the same efficiency without having to add more code in the shape of an existing operations. And yet that did not stop the committee from some particular [monolithic designs](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm)...

Comment: @AJG85: That is a nice looking bogus comment, which if followed would mean that if you want a sequential container and you want to sort it at some time or another you should use a `std::list`, as that is the only sequential container that offers a `sort` method, when in fact a `vector` will be more efficient for the task. The fact that the operation is implemented in the container does not imply that it will be more efficient than a freestanding operation, only that it will be more efficient than that freestanding operation when applied to this particular container.

Comment: @David: There are exceptions to every guideline that's why they're guidelines and not rules. In general lists are better at sorting than vectors because they're better at inserting, removing, and moving elements at any position within the container. That doesn't mean you couldn't find a situation where some implementation of sorting is better on a vector. It also doesn't mean that if you're going to sort ever you must use a list. It means *think* about what container is best for what you are going to do.

Answer (score 1):

Because dropping item from a list is cheap, while doing so on a vector is expensive - all following elements have to be shifted, i.e. copied/moved.

Comment: But just _finding_ the element in the list is equally expensive (linear time).  This is actually a very reasonable question.

Comment: Yes, how's that for usability design :)

Comment: IF remove() is not part of vector then why erase()?  erase also delete the element.

Comment: @Alok - you need to be able to remove from the `vector`, and given the way it works, its most efficient to remove contiguous chunks, which `erase` does, rather than random bits, which the remove-erase idiom does.  Granted it could just do the same, perhaps they are following Scott Meyer's "Prefer non-member non-friend functions to member functions" rule.  That works for `vector`, but in the case of `list`, its a member function to allow it to be done more efficiently.

Comment: @Alok: because `erase()` **must** be a member function, only container can erase its element, algorithms can only play with iterators, and `remove` actually does partitioning, so name maybe confusing, but algorithm is not.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine its due to efficiency, its slower to remove random elements from a vector than it is from a list.  It might mean a little more typing for situations like this, but at least its obvious in the interface that the `std::vector` isn't the best data structure if you need to do this often.